# Adversarial test against template generic STL vector pool

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management, strict-aliasing, type-punning

I have been coding C++ for many years. Most of my apps are built for solving problems in computational science/statistics/machine learning, so I have been extensively dealing with `std::vector`s storing large data. During these years, there's always an unconformable feeling like a splinter on the back of my head whenever I have the need for allocating temporary `std::vector`s inside a function. It incurs large overhead if the function is frequently called, and gets worse if the container is large or if the function runs in many threads.

My usual tactic is to write functions as functors, and set the temporary vectors as data members so they will be reused if the next call demands no greater capacity. If the memory resource is limited, I would need to manually scan the code, seek and elicit vectors of the same type elsewhere to reuse them.

For some larger apps, I often write a standalone struct `VecPool` that contains `vector< vector<typeNeeded> >`s. Temporary containers are fetched and returned during computation. In this case, I need to add new members to `VecPool` when new types show up, and it becomes messy or outright impossible if I want to templatize my class/function. The memory recycling efficiency is also low because containers of different types cannot be shared.

C++ standard pretty much prevents **reusing a memory buffer initialized with a different type**. For years I have been wanting to have a `VecPool` that recycles temporary `std::vector`s in the most parsimonious manner. Recently I finally made the determination to remove the splinter once for all.

I have the following demands:

1. `auto x = VecPool::give<T>(size1, ...)` will send me a vector or a nested vector. The innermost data type is `T`. For example, `auto x = VecPool::give<std::pair<double, std::set<int, float>>>(3, 2, 8, 5);` should yield a `vector<vector<vector<vector<std::pair<double, std::set<int, float>>>>>>`. In total, `x` is a composition of 1 + 3 + 3 x 2 + 3 x 2 x 8 = 58 `vector`s of various types. Function `VecPool::give` should fetch 58 `vector`s from the pool, construct `x` and return it.
2. `VecPool::recall(x)` will extract the 58 `vector`s in `x`, and push them back to the pool in the same order of them being pulled previously.

To achieve my goal, I used `std::vector<std::vector<char>>` as the pool container with a little hack. The implementation has minimal violation to the C++ standard. Here are some important considerations:

1. Standard >= C++17.
2. Memory alignment. This will not be an issue since the standard requires `malloc` return address that is at least `sizeof(size_t)` byte aligned.
3. How `std::vector` is implemented. The pool constructor should `static_assert` that the layout of `vector`'s header must be a 3-pointer. After the pointers are converted to integers `i0, i1, i2`, `i1 - i0` must equal the vector's size times the byte size of the element type; `i2 - i0` must equal the vector's capacity times the byte size of the element. If these requirements are not fulfilled, throw a runtime error.
4. When a `vector<char>` in the pool is adjusted to contain `T` before being dispatched, we need to adjust the 3rd pointer in the `vector` header to ensure the byte capacity is a multiple of the byte size of the element.

The following is my implementation. [Here is a copy](https://github.com/WhateverLiu/temp/blob/main/VecPool.hpp).

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


template<typename DestPtr, typename SourPtr>
inline void mmcp(DestPtr dest, SourPtr src, std::size_t Nbyte)
{ 
  std::memcpy((void*)dest, (void*)src, Nbyte);
}


template<typename T>
struct isVector { constexpr bool operator()() { return false; } };


template<typename T, typename A>
struct isVector<std::vector<T, A>> 
{ 
  constexpr bool operator()() { return true; };
};


// =============================================================================
// VecPool is not thread-safe. Create a VecPool for each thread.
// =============================================================================
class VecPool
{
private:
  std::vector<std::vector<char>> X;
  
  
  // ===========================================================================
  // Convert vector<T> to vector<char> that will be throw in pool.
  // ===========================================================================
  template<typename T>
  std::vector<char> T2char(std::vector<T> &x)
  { 
    static_assert(sizeof(x) == sizeof(std::vector<char>));
    x.resize(0); // Call destructors on all elements but keep capacity.
    std::vector<char> rst;
    char mem[sizeof(x)]; // Start swapping.
    mmcp(mem,  &rst, sizeof(x));
    mmcp(&rst, &x,   sizeof(x));
    mmcp(&x,   mem,  sizeof(x));
    return rst;
  }
  
  
  // ===========================================================================
  // Convert vector<char> in pool to vector<T>.
  // ===========================================================================
  template<typename T>
  std::vector<T> char2T(std::vector<char> &x)
  {  
    static_assert(sizeof(x) == sizeof(std::vector<T>));
    std::vector<T> rst;
    std::size_t mem[3];
    mmcp(mem, &x, sizeof(x));
    // =========================================================================
    // Adjust the capacity pointer to ensure the capacity is a multiple 
    //   of sizeof(T):
    // =========================================================================
    mem[2] -= (mem[2] - mem[0]) % sizeof(T);
    mmcp(&x,  &rst, sizeof(x));
    mmcp(&rst, mem, sizeof(x));
    return rst;
  }
  
  
  // ===========================================================================
  // Dispatch core function.
  // ===========================================================================
  template<typename T>
  std::vector<T> giveCore(std::size_t size)
  {
    if (X.size() == 0) 
    {
      std::vector<T> rst(size + 1); // Always prefer a little bit larger capacity.
      rst.pop_back();
      return rst;
    }
    auto rst = char2T<T> (X.back());
    rst.resize(size + 1); // Always prefer a little bit larger capacity.
    rst.pop_back();
    X.pop_back();
    return rst;
  }
  
  
  // ===========================================================================
  // Recall the vector of arbitrary type. The function will first clear
  // the vector --- call desctructor on all elements, and then take the
  // container back to pool.
  // ===========================================================================
  template<typename T>
  void recallCore(std::vector<T> &x) // Invalidates everything related to x.
  { 
    x.resize(0); // Call destructor on all elements.
    X.emplace_back(std::vector<char>(0));
    T2char(x).swap(X.back());
  }
  
  
public:
  VecPool()
  {
    std::srand(std::time(nullptr));
    test0();
    test1();
    test2();
    std::vector<std::vector<char>>(0).swap(X);
  }
  
  
  template <typename T, typename... Args>
  auto give(std::size_t size, Args... restSizes)
  {
    if constexpr (sizeof...(restSizes) == 0) return giveCore<T> (size);
    else 
    { 
      auto rst = giveCore< decltype( give<T>(restSizes...) ) > (size);
      for (auto &x: rst) give<T>(restSizes...).swap(x);
      return rst;
    }
  }
  
  
  template <typename T> 
  void recall(std::vector<T> &x)
  {
    if constexpr (isVector<T>()())
    { 
      for (auto i = x.rbegin(); i != x.rend(); ++i) recall(*i);  
      recallCore(x);
    }
    else recallCore(x);
  }
  
  
  void test0(); // Test if std::vector header is implemented as 3-pointer.
  void test1(); // Test if vectors fetched from or recalled to VecPool are handled correctly.
  void test2(); // Test if nested vectors can be handled correctly.
};


void VecPool::test0()
{
  static_assert( sizeof(std::size_t) == sizeof(void*) );
  
  
  // ===========================================================================
  // Test if std::vector is implemented in the way that can be exploited.
  // ===========================================================================
  unsigned fullSize = std::rand() % 31 + 17;
  unsigned subSize = fullSize - std::rand() % 13;
  
  
  typedef std::tuple<char, char, char> tupe; // Arbitrarily selected type.
  std::vector<tupe> a(fullSize); // Just for creating a vector of an arbitrary type.
  a.resize(subSize); // Downsize the vector.
  
  
  // ===========================================================================
  // To make VecPool work, vector header must contain exactly 3 pointers, 
  //   e.g. p1, p2, p3.
  // ===========================================================================
  static_assert( sizeof(a) == sizeof(std::size_t) * 3 );
  auto ptr = (std::size_t*)(&a); // Read but won't write.
  bool sizePointerCool     = ptr[0] + sizeof(tupe) * subSize  == ptr[1];
  bool capacityPointerCool = ptr[0] + sizeof(tupe) * fullSize == ptr[2];
  
  
  if (!sizePointerCool or !capacityPointerCool) throw std::runtime_error(
      "VecPool initialization: Layout of std::vector header is unsupported.\n");
}




// ===========================================================================
// Test 1 to run during initialization. Check memory addresses and if the 
//   container dispatched from VecPool can call push()/emplace_back().
// ===========================================================================
void VecPool::test1()
{
  std::size_t asize = std::rand() % 7 + 3;
  auto a = give<float> (asize);
  a.resize(asize);
  void *aptr = a.data();
  
  
  int bsize = std::rand() % 5 + 3;
  auto b = give<std::tuple<short, short, short> >(bsize);
  void *bptr = b.data();
  
  
  recall(b);
  recall(a);
  
  
  if ( (void*)(X.back().data()) != aptr ) throw std::runtime_error(
    "VecPool initialization: Last in pool is a different container.\n");
  
  
  if ( (void*)(X[X.size() - 2].data()) != bptr ) throw std::runtime_error(
    "VecPool initiailization: Second last in pool is a different container.\n");
  
  
  typedef std::tuple<char, char, char, char, char, char, char> tupe;
  int lastContainerByteCapa = X.back().capacity();
  int pushTimes = lastContainerByteCapa / sizeof(tupe) + 5;
  auto c = give<tupe>(0);
  
  
  // =========================================================================
  // Test emplace_back() beyond the vector's capacity.
  // =========================================================================
  for (int i = 0; i < pushTimes; ++i) c.emplace_back(tupe());
  int dsize = c.capacity() - c.size() + 3;
  
  
  auto d = give<double>(dsize);
  auto dptr = d.data() + 1;
  recall(d);
  if (std::size_t(X.back().data()) + sizeof(double) != std::size_t(dptr) ) 
    throw std::runtime_error(
        "VecPool initiailization: Last in pool is a different container -- 2.\n");
}


// Find address of the first element in a vector. Used in test2().
template <typename T>
void FindAddrsOfAllVectorsInNestedVector(T &x, std::vector<std::size_t> &addrs)
{
  if constexpr (!isVector<T>()()) return;
  else
  {
    static_assert( sizeof(std::size_t) == sizeof(x.data()) );
    addrs.emplace_back(std::size_t(x.data()));
    for (auto &u: x) FindAddrsOfAllVectorsInNestedVector(u, addrs);
  }
}


// ===========================================================================
// Test 2 to run during initialization. Test if VecPool correctly deals with
//   nested vectors.
// ===========================================================================
void VecPool::test2()
{
  int a[7];
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) a[i] = rand() % 3 + 1;
  auto x = give<float> ( // x is a 7-d vector.
    a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6]);
  std::vector<std::size_t> addresses;
  FindAddrsOfAllVectorsInNestedVector(x, addresses);
  recall(x);
  for (int i = X.size() - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; --i, ++j)
  { 
    auto addr = std::size_t(X[i].data());
    if (addresses[j] != addr) throw std::runtime_error(
      "VecPool initialization: Nested vector test failed.\n");
  }
} 


// =============================================================================
// Usage pattern goes like this:
// =============================================================================
// VecPool vp;
// auto a = vp.give<int> (3);
// auto b = vp.give<double>(5, 7);
// auto c = vp.give<std::tuple<short, short, short> >(2);
// 
// ......
// 
// vp.recall(c); // Recalls are not necessary but good to do.
// vp.recall(b);
// vp.recall(a);
// =============================================================================
// It is strongly recommended that the first dispatched gets recalled last,
//   so the next code run will always utilize the same containers.
// =============================================================================


// ===========================================================================
// Code pattern for creating a vector of vectors of different sizes.
// ===========================================================================
// auto v = vp.give< std::vector<std::vector<int>> > (3); // A vector of vector of vectors.
// for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
// {
//   vp.give<std::vector<int>>(i * 2 + 1).swap(v[i]);
//   for (int j = 0, jend = v[i].size(); j < jend; ++j)
//     vp.give<int>(j + 5).swap(v[i][j]);
// }
```

I have run extensive tests and have plugged it in my projects. There has been no problem so far.

**Besides the obvious problem of the code**, can anyone write a standard-conformant test case that will break it, i.e. make it go wrong? If you have better ideas of achieving what I want, I would be more than happy to hear about them!

Replies to some comments:

My goal is not just about reusing memory, but really reusing vectors which have so many member functions that I like, e.g. emplace_back(). Of course it is not the most efficient function if you did not reserve space, but there are many situations where you cannot guess a sufficient capacity.

Nested vectors are indeed not the most efficient, but there are many occasions when using data cube is a massive waste of memory or downright infeasible.

Comment: I think there are some advanced topics called [Allocators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory#Allocators) and also [Memory Resource](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory#Memory_resources_.28since_C.2B.2B17.29) which may interest you.

Comment: I think a custom allocator would be a much simpler approach, you can then just have a pool of raw memory. At an even lower level something like tcmalloc could help too

Comment: The question itself might be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If performances are a concern, usually nested vectors are not a really good idea (except if they are not meant to be resized)

Comment: @kiner_shah I have basic understanding of allocator and memory resource. Do you suggest that the combination of these two can avoid type punning for recycling memory resources of different types?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Could you give me a general direction to achieving my goal using custom allocator? I still cannot figure out how to avoid type punning based on my rudimentary understanding of the subject

Comment: @user2961927: The general idea is that `VecPool` is an *allocator* that tracks recent allocations. Then your code can create a `std::vector<T, VecPool>` and it will use the memory from your `VecPool`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/allocators?view=msvc-170

Comment: The easiest entry into using a special purpose allocator is using [std::pmr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/memory_resource). As you can see the allocators' `do_allocate` and `do_deallocate` functions only operate on `void*`, so the type information is completely erased (which is being paid for with a runtime overhead). `std::pmr` comes with a handful predefined allocators implementing different strategies (even stack based storage), which one is the best suited for your use case you have to decide form yourself (or if you want to roll your own implementation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is super dangerous because you're `memcpy`ing around internals of `std::vector`, which is... not safe. But your real goal appears to be simply to reuse *memory* rather than reusing vectors. C++ actually has built-in facilities for this: customizable allocators.  What you're really wanting is a pool allocator, such as those found in [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/pool/doc/index.html).

If, however, you want to make your code work, then what you want is for something like this to work:

```
VecPool vp;

std::vector<int, VecPoolAllocator<int>> a = vp.get<int>(3);
```

And then the `std::vector` will use the `vp` for allocating and deallocating memory. You'll want to make a `VecPool` object that can maintain a list of freed memory and attempt to reuse that memory for subsequent memory allocations. Something like this:

```
class VecPool {
private:
    std::vector<std::pair<std::size_t,std::unique_ptr<char[]>>> X;
public:
    char* allocate(std::size_t size) {
        for(auto it=X.begin(); it!=X.end(); it++) {
            if (it->first >= size) {
                char* memory = it->second.release();
                X.erase(it);
                return memory;
            }
        }
        return new char[size];
    }
    void deallocate(char* ptr, std::size_t size) noexcept {
        // If this fails to allocate, thats undefined behavior! 
        X.emplace_back(size, std::unique_ptr<char[]>{ptr});
    }
}
```

You'll also want an allocator object that tells the `std::vector` how to interact with your `VecPool`:

```
template<class T>
class VecPoolAlloc {
    VecPool* base_;
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using is_alwyas_equal = std::false_type;
    using propagate_on_container_copy_assignment = std::true_type;
    using propagate_on_container_move_assignment = std::true_type;
    using propagate_on_container_swap = std::true_type;
    
    VecPoolAlloc(const VecPool& base) noexcept : base_(const_cast<VecPool*>(&base)) {}
    template<class U> VecPoolAlloc(const VecPoolAlloc<U>& rhs) noexcept : base_(rhs.base_) {}
    template<class U> VecPoolAlloc& operator=(const VecPoolAlloc<U>& rhs) noexcept {base_=rhs.base_; return *this;}
    T* allocate(std::size_t size) {return reinterpret_cast<T*>(base_->allocate(size*sizeof(T)));}
    void deallocate(T* ptr, std::size_t size) noexcept {base_->deallocate(reinterpret_cast<char*>(ptr), size*sizeof(T));}
    template<class U> bool operator==(const VecPoolAlloc<U>&rhs) noexcept {return base_==rhs.base_;}
};
```

And that's the basic functionality. You just have to make sure to always pass the `vp` as the last parameter to the `std::vector` constructors.

---

However, the need to write `std::vector<std::vector<int, VecPoolAllocator<int>>, VecPoolAllocator<std::vector<int, VecPoolAllocator<int>>>>` and similar is obnoxious for parameters and return types and such, so since you mention that nested vectors is common for your use case, you might as well make helper methods for those:

```
    template<class T, std::size_t depth> struct pool_vec_finder;
    template<class T> struct pool_vec_finder<T,1> {
        using value_type = T;
        using type = std::vector<value_type, VecPoolAlloc<value_type>>;
    };
    template<class T, std::size_t depth> struct pool_vec_finder {
        using value_type = pool_vec_finder<T, depth-1>::type; 
        using type = std::vector<value_type, VecPoolAlloc<value_type>>;
    };
    template<class T, std::size_t depth=1>
    using pool_vector = pool_vec_finder<T, depth>::type;
```

And then you can pass around `pool_vector<int,2>` instead, which is *far* easier to type and understand.

---

Oh, and you wanted `give<T>(size_t...)` methods as well? Done.

```
    template<class T>
    pool_vector<T> give(std::size_t count) {
        return pool_vector<T>(count, *this);
    }
    template<class T, class...sizets>
    pool_vector<T, sizeof...(sizets)+1> give(std::size_t count, sizets...sizes)
    {
        pool_vector<T, sizeof...(sizets)+1> temp(count, give<T>(sizes...), *this);
        return temp;
    }
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ccfc359a1819872f

---

As a final note, since this *is* an abstract allocator, you can actually use it with other structures too.

```
VecPool vp;
std::list<int, VecPoolAllocator<int>> myList(vp);
std::dequeue<int, VecPoolAllocator<int>> myDeque(vp);
std::set<int, std::less<int>, VecPoolAllocator<int>> mySet(vp);
std::map<int, char, std::less<int>, VecPoolAllocator<std::pair<const int, char>>> myMap(vp);
```

And it'll simply reuse memory allocations between all of these, no problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have one question. Suppose I request a vector from your initial pool, and I start do push_back(). Once the capacity is exceeded, it will request another vector of twice the capacity. Then it seems the pool will retain the obsolete vector? If I continue doing push_back(), there could be many obsolete vectors in pool in the end. Is it possible to prevent that from happening?

Comment: I also want to adjust the .allocate() to make it always pop out the last container in X. My thinking is that if I have a function that requires 3 temp vectors, the next time I call it in a tight loop will guarantee the same vectors will be used --- provided that the function does not change their capacities. The hacky code I wrote tried to satisfy this:D I need to think harder to make it work in the paradigm of a custom allocator.. Please let me know if you have any good idea!

Comment: @user2961927: when you do repeated `push_back`, then `std::vector` will request ~2x as much memory from the pool, and then return the old memory to the pool. Eventually, there can be many obsolete memory blocks in the pool in the end, yes.  You can customize whatever solution you like inside the pool `allocate` and `deallocate` methods. I just tried to approximate something similar to what you started with.

Comment: Also note that if you have an empty vector, and push back 1000 integers: the first push_back will make the vector allocate ~32 bytes (8 ints), and the 9th push_back will allocate ~64 bytes (16 ints), and then 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096 bytes. So there would only be ~7 extra memory buffers in the cache, which would simply be reused by whatever next thing needed memory.

Comment: @MooningDuck  Thanks for the reply. Forgive my ignorance, but why do I feel the elimination of the obsolete  vectors during push_back is impossible? How are we able to inform allocate() and deallocate() that they are being called inside vector::push_back()?

Comment: @user2961927: To match your `recallCore`, the impl would simply be `void deallocate(char* ptr, std::size_t size) noexcept {
        if (!X.isEmpty()) { delete[] X.back().second; X.pop_back();}
        X.emplace_back(size, std::unique_ptr<char[]>{ptr});
    }`
And then `X` only keeps the last single buffer returned. Of course, there's no reason for `X` to be a `vector` itself that way.

Comment: After long complementation, although the answer is not fully satisfactory to what I want, it opens the door to so many possibilities.. Thanks a lot!